# how to get 'Queries per second avg' using SQL (not 'mysqladmin status')

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

When I start `mysqladmin`, it prints out several statistics, including "Queries per second avg":

```
# mysqladmin --defaults-file=../mylogin.cnf status
Uptime: 4568115  Threads: 859  Questions: 3703806462  Slow queries: 19415  Opens: 10300505  Flush tables: 247  Open tables: 2000  Queries per second avg: 810.795
```

Can I retrieve this "Queries per second avg" value within an SQL query? We use MariaDB 10.1.x

Answer (score 5):

For those running MariaDB and MySQL (If using 5.7, [show_compatibility_56](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_compatibility_56) enabled)

```
SELECT Q / T Queries_per_second_avg FROM
(SELECT variable_value Q FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Questions') A,
(SELECT variable_value T FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Uptime') B;
```

For those running MySQL 5.7, [show_compatibility_56](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_compatibility_56) disabled

```
SELECT Q / T Queries_per_second_avg FROM
(SELECT variable_value Q FROM performance_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Questions') A,
(SELECT variable_value T FROM performance_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Uptime') B;
```

Comment: 'Questions' doesn't include statements executed within stored programs -- use 'Queries' instead if you want to include those. You can also use 'Com_select', 'Com_insert', 'Com_delete', 'Com_update' to get numbers for certain types of queries, though these values don't include query cache hits.

Comment: @dbdemon You are right, I mentioned that 3 years ago : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102265/how-mysql-queries-and-questions-status-variables-are-calculated/102286#102286